# why am I getting segmentation fault? I am trying to solve the rat in a maze problem

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, backtracking

why am I getting segmentation fault? I am trying to solve the rat in a maze problem.
Below is the code that is giving me the segmentation fault
May be there is some fault is passing 2D array to functions but seems alright to me
I have applied the base conditions in function rinm and passing the solution matrix as well as the user input matrix from the main().

```
bool rinm(int** maze,int** sol,int n, int x, int y)
{
    if(x==n-1 && y==n-1)
    {
            sol[x][y]=1;

        //print the path
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            /* code */
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                cout<<sol[i][j]<<" ";

            }

            cout<<endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=n || y>=n || maze[x][y]==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    sol[x][y]=1;

    bool up=rinm(maze,sol,n,x-1,y);
    bool down=rinm(maze,sol,n,x+1,y);
    bool right=rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y+1);
    bool left = rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y-1);
   
    sol[x][y]=0;

    if(up||down||right||left)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my main function.

```
 int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int** maze=new int*[n];//rows
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            maze[i]=new int [n]; // columns
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<n;j++)
            {
                cin>>maze[i][j];
            }
        }
    
        int** sol=new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            sol[i]=new int [n]; // columns
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<n;j++)
            {
                sol[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        bool path=rinm(maze,sol,n,0,0);
        if(path==false)
            cout<<"path doesnot exist\n";
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: This loop will work infinite because you have not stored any visited state array. Let's say the input is
`2
1 1
0 1`
    then you keep revisiting the 1s through up and down function calls

Comment: Can you please specify what is the `rat in a maze problem`?

Comment: @risingStark can you please elaborate what I need to modify? I have added the base conditions and also when I need to return false....

Comment: @risingStark can you please elaborate what I need to modify? I have added the base conditions and also when I need to return false....

Comment: What happens when you run in a debugger - you can see the line that fails and the values of the variables

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that keep revisiting the same cells because you have not checked whether you are visiting a cell for the first time or not.

For example for the input:

```
2
1 1
0 1
```

I will enter the sequence of moves of `(x, y)` and you can see that it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
(0, 0) 
    -> (-1, 0) (up function call, returns false since x < 0)
    -> (1, 0) (down function call, return false since maze[1][0] = 0)
    -> (0, 1) 
           -> (-1, 1) (up function call, returns false since x < 0)
           -> (1, 1) (down function call, solution found. Print sol matrix)
           -> (0, 2) (right function call, returns false since y >= 2)
           -> (0, 0) (left function call)
```

The problem lies here. Now you are back to `(0, 0)` and the recursion keeps on running without any termination. This results in huge memory allocation of recursion stack and you get **Segmentation Fault**.

I hope you are able to understand the problem here. If you are still in doubt, just print `(x, y)` as soon as you enter the loop and you will see this happening.

Here are the changes I made in the code.[image: Here are the changes I made in the code]
Here's the corrected code. This will print all available paths to reach the destination.
The function returns false if `sol[x][y] == 1` which means that you have visited the cell `(x, y)` earlier as well.

```
bool rinm(int** maze,int** sol,int n, int x, int y)
{
    if(x==n-1 && y==n-1)
    {
            sol[x][y]=1;

        //print the path
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            /* code */
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                cout<<sol[i][j]<<" ";

            }

            cout<<endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=n || y>=n || maze[x][y]==0 || sol[x][y]==1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    sol[x][y]=1;

    bool up=rinm(maze,sol,n,x-1,y);
    bool down=rinm(maze,sol,n,x+1,y);
    bool right=rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y+1);
    bool left = rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y-1);
   
    sol[x][y]=0;

    if(up||down||right||left)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

To print any one path to the destination, you can keep a global variable and initialize that variable whenever any path is found and then return false again if that variable is initialized. The code for just one path path is below.

```
int c = 0;
bool rinm(int** maze,int** sol,int n, int x, int y)
{
    if(x==n-1 && y==n-1)
    {
        c = 1;
            sol[x][y]=1;

        //print the path
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            /* code */
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                cout<<sol[i][j]<<" ";

            }

            cout<<endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=n || y>=n || maze[x][y]==0 || sol[x][y]==1 || c == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    sol[x][y]=1;

    bool up=rinm(maze,sol,n,x-1,y);
    bool down=rinm(maze,sol,n,x+1,y);
    bool right=rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y+1);
    bool left = rinm(maze,sol,n,x,y-1);
   
    sol[x][y]=0;

    if(up||down||right||left)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are the changes represented for easy understanding. [image: Here are the changes represented for easy understanding.]

Comment: but buddy for n=4  1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1
 1 0 1 1 I am getting an extra output with this code.

Comment: @BikramjitDas Can you post some screenshot of this because I am getting just one output for the above test case. The output I got is `1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 
'

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using native 2d arrays. Replace them with a simple 1d valarray or vector and access it's elements using you own simple method that transforms x and y coords into a simple index. You'll save yourself from many headaches...

```
class Maze
{
    private:
    std::valarray<int> _data;
    int _width, _height;

    public:
    Maze(int width, int height) : _data(width * height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
    }

    int& item(int x, int y)
    {
        return _data[y * _width + x];
    }

    // ...
}
```